# Thread.sleep and System.currentTimeMillis

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a program which is running on windows system. With logic something like below. I see that the Thread is acutally sleeping for 60 seconds but the timestamps and the duration printed are 55 seconds. As far as i know both Thread.sleep and System.currentTimeMillis depend on system time. Why do i see this difference

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  logger.info("Started");
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

  logger.info("No Arguments passed waiting for 60 seconds....");
  Thread.sleep(60000);

  logger.info("Sleep Duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
  logger.info("Ended");
 }
```

Comment: I tried simulating this on my MAC but I am seeing an expected answer. I did it on my Mac OS

Comment: Can u try it once more? Does it always `55` ?

Comment: Not always it differs. Some time it matches. I just wanted to understand what does Thread.sleep do to be more accurate.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana, probably your computer synchronizes the system time with internet server? Usually it's performed not by immediate jump, but by gradual changes (this way most of programs don't get crazy). Check this and disable network time synchronization. If my guess is correct, then actually the `sleep` is moreless accurate, but `System.currentTimeMillis()` difference is not.

Comment: are you running on a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes this in on a virtual machine. Sorry i missed this part in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thread.sleep causes the currently executing thread to sleep
>   (temporarily cease execution) for the specified duration, subject to
>   the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread
>   does not lose ownership of any monitors, and resumption of execution
>   will depend on scheduling and the availability of processors on which
>   to execute the thread.

In any case, you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified.

Comment: Even that, it should not differ by 5 seconds. Even 5 milliseconds is bad I guess. Unless, the jvm impl on windows is really bad or the windows is really bad.

Comment: Usually it sleeps a little bit longer than requested and I never observed that it's five seconds shorter. The OPs experience is indeed strange.

Comment: @EricWang, 5 milliseconds is probably possible on Windows XP... It had very rough timer behind `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: @TagirValeev I did a little test, and added an answer, you are right, OP's test result is wield for sure. In modern computer & OS & jvm, it should be less than 1 milliseconds I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As `@Tagir_Valeev` said, your windows's scheduler is not that good, this is one major reason I guess.

Another reason is that, there are `logger.info()` between the 2 time point, that would take up to several milliseconds maybe.

So, write your program in following way might make it more accurate.

**SleepAccuracyTest.java:** (*a `TestNG` class, use `Slf4j` as logger*)

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

// test sleep accuracy,
public class SleepAccuracyTest {
    public static final int MAX_DIFF = 1; // max diff in milliseconds,
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SleepAccuracyTest.class);
    private int counter = 0;

    @Test(invocationCount = 10, alwaysRun = true)
    public void testIt() {
        int during = 1000;
        counter++;
        try {
            logger.info("Started [{}]", counter);
            logger.info("No Arguments passed waiting for {} milliseconds...", during);

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread.sleep(during);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long actualDuring = end - start;
            long diff = actualDuring - during;
            Assert.assertTrue(Math.abs(diff) <= MAX_DIFF);

            logger.info("Expected during: {}, actual duration: {}, diff: {}", during, actualDuring, diff);
            logger.info("Ended\n");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Test result:**

On my machine (*64bit linux-3.16, Java8, 4 cpu*):

- When running your code, it has 1 ~ 6 milliseconds diff,
- When run my code above, most of times it has 0 diff, sometimes it diff by 1 millisecond (I guess the 1 millisecond is just a round-off).

So, the `logger.info()` or `System.out.printf()` parts also takes times.
But only several milliseconds, never seconds.